# Metrics converter app

Tags: c++, winapi

I'd like to make a metrics converter app. When you type something in one edit control value in the other one changes. If you change value of the second edit control, the first one will be changed to correct value. My question is how to recognize if edit box was edited by program's user or just by itself (using SendMessage or sth like that)? Is it possible or do I have to add a "Convert" button?

Comment: You use raw win32 api or something like ATL or MFC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for [EN_CHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761676%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notification message. The resulting code can be:

```
switch(uMsg)
{
  case WM_COMMAND:
     if((HIWORD(wParam) == EN_CHANGE) && 
         (LOWORD(wParam) == YOUR_IDC_EDIT))   //control ID
     {
      // Do your converting and text setting here  
     }
     break;
}
```

Comment: I did it, but maybe I did it wrong. When user changes 1st edit box it will edit 2nd edit box(using SendDlgItemMessage), which will then edit 1st edit box and so on. Infinite loop.

Comment: Then only react to the change message if the control has the focus.

Comment: @user that won't work with automation, for instance. A better solution is to note that you are in an updating state and suppress change notification handling whilst updating.

Comment: Thank you user2225104, it works, I didn't think of it, 'cuz it wasn't in edit controls overview at the MSDN.

Comment: @PiotrSyrokomski You should take into account David Heffernan's comment regarding your conversion paradigm. He raises a valid point there.

Comment: @David Sorry, but I cannot understand what you say. I don't know what automation is, and what does "suppress change notification handling". English is not my native language. Solution, that user2225104 gave me works right now.

Comment: It is possible for the control's text to change even if it does not have the focus.

Comment: How would you do that being an application user?

Comment: Using automation for example

Comment: Again, I don't know what automation is. Edit: Ok I found what it is. You said, that: "A better solution is to note that you are in an updating state and suppress change notification handling whilst updating", but how do I do it, if the only way to check if edit control was edited is through notifications?

Comment: Your application can store state in variables

Comment: Ok, I set update state, update text and then what? I wait for notification from another edit control, discard it and set normal state? How do I know, if notification from another control is something I want to discard, or if it's just user that changed it so fast (using automation)?